# Template for a solution manual

Tags: math-mode

I want to write a book with solutions to a book I am reading. My first attempt so far was to just use an ad-hoc solution, but I am quite unhappy how it looks.

A small excerpt of what I did:

```
\chapter*{Lecture 3: Bla Bla}

\subsection*{3.1} 

(a) Answer

(b) Another answer 

\subsection*{3.2} 

Unsolved

\subsection*{3.3}

Bla Bla Bla answer
```

Can someone recommend a template/package I can use? Also, if you have recommendation on how to manage such projects it will be helpful.

Here are examples that I think are good [(1)](https://github.com/zhengqigao/PRML-Solution-Manual/blob/master/PRML_Solution_Manual.pdf) and [(2)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/prml-web-sol-2009-09-08.pdf).

**Note**: Existing questions do not apply to my case. I am not interested in question/answer templates. I mainly want to write solutions to exercises.

Comment: You may want to try or read the manual from package èxam` https://ctan.org/pkg/exam , which provides both questions and answers. // Find more related packages here  https://ctan.org/topic/exam . // Package `xsim` is a bit more complicated, but also more versatile to use: https://ctan.org/pkg/xsim . // All these are used at school or universities by teachers.

Comment: Refering to your 2 examples, you probably only look for ways to modify the layout, i.e. the look and feel. Contentwise your code fragment is fine, in my view. // Do you know math-mode and its related packages?

Comment: xsim sounds like a good package. @MS-SPO What do you mean by math-mode? Do you mean [this](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Mathematical_expressions). If yes, then I know, otherwise no.

Comment: Right, for inline and blockwise equations.